# transparent images on imagick without dark background

Tags: php, png, transparency, imagick

being completely new to **Imagick** and to image processing in general, I tried to set a `Sagittarius` symbol png on `50% transparency` over a background (the hand/tree image), another png.

This is the result I got, with an unwanted grey part around the Sagittarius symbol.

**50% transparency png:**

[image]

How can I remove that? I tried with different combinations but nothing worked. This is the code so far

```
$baseIGmeme = "basetree.png";
$strInputFile = "sagittarius.png";
$target = 'final.png';
$im = new Imagick($strInputFile);
$im->setImageFormat('png');
$im->transparentPaintImage($im->getImageBackgroundColor(), 0.5, 10000, FALSE);  // paintTransparentImage method is deprecated.
$im->setImageAlpha(0.5);
$imbase = new Imagick($baseIGmeme);
$imbase->compositeImage($im, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER , 450, 350);
$imbase->writeImage($target);
```

I tried with this code but the results aren't fine

```
thanks, I try with this code but I don't know what I do wrong

$s1= new Imagick("basetree.png");
$s2= new Imagick("sagittarius.png");

// setImageFormat probably not needed but the result doesn't change
$s1->setImageFormat ('png'); $s2->setImageFormat ('png');
$s2->setImageBackgroundColor("transparent");
$s2->setImageAlpha(0.5);
$s2->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
$s1->compositeImage($s2, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT,450,350, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
```

[new try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBWtW.jpg)

also adding

```
    $s2->setImageMatte(TRUE);
```

didn't change the result.

If instead of
Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA
I use
Imagick::CHANNEL_DEFAULT)
I get transparency but still with the grey area

[image]

I want something like this (made in a quick way with Canva)
[image]

Comment: thanks, I try with this code but I don't know what I do wrong